# Ubuntu stuck on login screen

Tags: login

I have a small issue with my Ubuntu (I think After an upgarde).
When I try to login (Login Screen), I get disconnected and get back to the screen (again & again).

I tried:

- Trying to login with others Desktop environements.
- Booting from old kernel.
- log in via command line [`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`].
- removing `~/.gconf` directory.
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install unity`

None of these solutions worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell using your username and your password. In this case username will be your username you set when you installed Ubuntu.

Now run `ls -lah` and look for the output line that ends with .Xauthority

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try logging in.

Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either

*Make sure you are connected to internet with DHCP on.*

1. `sudo apt-get purge lightdm`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
4. `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Now type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart.

Comment: thank you sir, problem solved after reinstalling lightdm

Comment: Used this method to get an install on an old eeePC working. Thank you.

Comment: thank you! This answer solved my problem twice.
Once it was .Xauthority this time it was lightdm

Comment: I had multiple desktop environments installed - and when this happened for GNOME, I tried logging into Xfce and it worked.