# Caught in login loop after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, can't login to the root either

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login

I am totally new to Ubuntu which came pre-installed in my laptop. I upgraded to 14.04 version but I think it was not installed properly when I restarted the system. Now it is not letting me login even though I am entering the right password. I read somewhere to enter into root but I can't as I don't get any screen on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: Please provide some details regarding the hardware (in particular the graphics module) and the way you upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Its a Dell 15 3452. I upgraded by going into system settings but i know it didnot complete properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by doing this:

It's not just <kbd>F3</kbd> but it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell. Also, I've seen laptops that have the behavior of the FN and F buttons reversed, meaning that you have to press the FN button to actually press the F key. I have no idea why but the N5010 is such a model.

Assuming we get that far, run

```
ls -lah
```

If in the output the line is along these lines:

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```

and try logging in.

Else, do

```
ls -ld /tmp
```

Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: drwxrwxrwt.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do

```
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

or uninstall, reinstall it.
Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> until you reach the login screen again, and restart.

Please note that this was not *my* solution. I found the answer at this site in a post such as this one:

[Ubuntu stuck on login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551991/ubuntu-stuck-login-screen)

I'm unable to find the exact post that I initially found but this one is similar/close enough and I'd saved the information just to be able to it again if I needed it.

Comment: @NeelamAhlawat - I just want to check to see if you managed to resolve this. If you haven't then, by all means, let us know and someone may have another route to try.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29936/discussion-on-answer-by-kgiii-caught-in-login-loop-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14).

Comment: This problem is so pervasive but so far there is no definitely answer...