# No user shows up in login screen

Tags: login-screen, 21.10

When I get to the login screen, it appears as normal, except no user is selectable and the ubuntu logo on the bottom of the screen is missing as well. When I restart the machine several times, my user shows up eventually.

While I have found information about other problems with the login screen ([Login not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170650/ubuntu-does-no-let-me-log-in-to-my-user-how-can-i-fix-it), [Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551991/ubuntu-stuck-on-login-screen)) but nothing like my problem.

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: If it works after several reboots I suspect you might have a failing hard drive. Or maybe a crupted file system?

Comment: @David Its a SSD that I bought new a month ago.

Comment: Hard drives can fail brand new.

Comment: @David I followed this guide: https://ttrdatarecovery.com/check-ssd-health-step-by-step-guide/ to check whether my drive is ok, and it passes the health ckeck